# Multipart email best practices

Tags: email

I am developing a web app that sends out emails. Currently, all emails have a HTML part.

Questions:

1. Is it important to include a text part also?
2. Do you include both?
3. Is just removing all the tags from the HTML message and adding a few line breaks good enough to create a text part from the HTML part?

Thanks, Kevin

Comment: What platform/technologies are you using to develop your app?

Comment: Apache 2.2, php 5.  Nothing atypical.  How does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Is it Important to include a text part also?** It's a best practice to provide a plain text version of the email.  However, in my opinion and in this day and age, I would guess that it is not such a big deal to leave it out.  However, if you know more about your recipients' email clients (eg: if you're sending the emails in a corporate environment and everyone uses a particular email client), then you can determine how necessary it really is.
2. **Do you include both?**  The .net framework (which I use) provides an [AlternateView class (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.alternateview.aspx) that allows you to easily specify copies of an email in different formats.  It makes things very easy to include a plain text version of the email.  Perhaps you can find something similar in apache/php.
3. **Is just removing all the tags from the HTML message and adding a few line breaks good enough to create a text part from the HTML part?**  Technically, yes but be VERY CAREFUL here.  A complex HTML layout that has been converted to plain text will look absolutely terrible if all you do is remove HTML tags and pile the content together.  It really depends on your content and how much you can do to manipulate said content.  Also, take a look at Campaign Monitor's[suggestions for formatting plain text emails](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/entry/661/plain-text-templates-and-formatting-tips/).

One final word of advice for you HTML emails to test, test, and then test some more.  When you're finished testing, test again.  HTML emails will render differently in different email clients and, if some of your recipients are using Microsoft Word 2007/2010 then you can forget about web standards.  I urge you to take a look at [Campaign Monitor's Guide to CSS support in email](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Comment: Removing tags from HTML message and adding a few line breaks are definitely good enough for text version, you just have to set the `Content-Type:` for the part properly.